# Log Exception using NLog

Tags: c#, xamarin, nlog

In the NLog wiki page I found this [Page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions) describes how to log exception. But in the page they have mentioned something like this to achieve the feature.

```xml
<nlog> 
  <targets> 
    <target name="f" type="File" 
            layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/> 
  </targets> 
  <rules> 
    <logger name="*" writeTo="f"/> 
  </rules> 
</nlog>
```

I am dynamically creating the configuration file and not sure how to implement the above configuration into my code.

**The code for configuration is**

```
public class NLogManager : ILogManager
{
        public NLogManager()
        {
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

            var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget();
            config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

            var consoleRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, consoleTarget);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(consoleRule);

            var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
            string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            fileTarget.FileName = Path.Combine(folder, "Log.txt");
            config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

            var fileRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Warn, fileTarget);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(fileRule);

            LogManager.Configuration = config;
        }

        public ILogger GetLog([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "")
        {
            string fileName = callerFilePath;

            if (fileName.Contains("/"))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 1);
            }

            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(fileName);
            return new NLogLogger(logger);
        }
    }
```

Can any one suggest me how I can configure this dynamically?

Comment: What needs to be dynamically?

Comment: How I ca write exception into log? How I can configure that in above code? right now If i give like this  log?.Error(newExc, "TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException") only message is coming

Comment: I thought the xml is doing something same  in config file. In my case i don't have a config file maintained in the app. Instead I am using the above given C# code logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Layout` property on the (file) `Target`:

```
fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";
```

note: the default layout is `${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}` and won't include the exception as you can see. This will be changed in NLog 5 or 6: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1292